# Devexpress GridView MouseDown only work once

Tags: c#, gridview, mousedown

When I implement the MouseDown event of the GridView, after I click on one cell,the MouseDown event is called sucessfully,then I click on the same cell,the MouseDown event is **not** called,However I Click somewhere else and click back,it works.

```
private void view_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PreviewMouseDown` event. Events PreviewMouseDown and MouseDown use a different routing strategy.
MouseDown - Bubbling.
PreviewMouseDown - Tunneling.